# sympy TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: sympy

I'd like to get a symbolic derivative of an expression with multiple variables where a variable name can be more than one character.

This works great:

```
expr = '3*a+2*b+1'
diff(expr, 'a')
3
diff(expr, 'b')
2
```

This also works:

```
expr = '3*alpha++1'
diff(expr, 'alpha')
3
```

But this fails:

```
expr = '3*alpha+2*beta+1'
diff(expr, 'alpha')
ValueError: Error from parse_expr with transformed code: "Integer (3 )\*Symbol ('alpha' )+Integer (2 )\*beta +Integer (1 )"
```

Is there a way to make this work?

What's interesting is, is that this works:

```
expr = '3*alpha+2*b+1'
diff(expr, 'alpha')
3
diff(expr, 'b')
2
```

But this again doesn't:

```
expr = '3*a+2*beta+1'
diff(expr, 'a')
```

Comment: Try `type(beta)`.  I suspect that with the star imports `beta` is a defined function.  Test your strings with `sympify`.  `sympy` has to first parse the string to a expression before doing the `diff`.  `sympify('3*alpha+2*b+1')`

Comment: Notice how the error, `Symbol ('alpha' )` and `beta` have been parsed differently.  That means `beta` has already been defined, and isn't available as free symbol.  Also the full error include `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Integer' and 'FunctionClass'`

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Is there no means to override a predefined symbol? Also, would you know if I can get a list of defined symbols?